# Script To Copy Format No Longer Working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that I paste entire rows into from a different sheet. I then run a script that does a couple of things, including copying the format of the row above (so that the validation and date formats are added to the new row).

I've always done this with:

```
templateRange.copyTo(targetRange, {formatOnly:true})
```

In my definitions, `templateRange` is:

```
var templateRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(rowAbove, 1, 1, 36)
```

And `targetRange` is:

```
 var targetRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(rowNumber, 1, 1, 36)
```

This approach has worked flawlessly for months. Even years.

But recently--with NO changes to the script--it's stopped working.

Anybody have any ideas what's gone wrong?

Comment: Is it still failing? I tried it and worked for me. I also tried with this function: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyFormatToRange(Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I've solved my own problem. Turns out `copyTo` with `formatOnly:true` is still working fine. But that function is apparently no longer copying data validation or dates. To do that, I needed to use the DataValidation Class. Same story for the date. Pain in the knee. But at least I got my script operational again.